# Is it possible to escape/beat the Yiga clan if they find you in their hideout?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I got caught a few times and it always resultet in a Game Over because you're overwhelmed by lots of powerful enemies. I don't really plan on trying this out myself (I already cleared the hideout, so they are gone anyway), but is it possible to defeat the Yiga clan if they find you?

The reason I ask is because it seems to be a guaranteed Game Over:

- the gates close
- the big guys BARELY even flinch, even with powerful melee weapons
- unlike all other deaths, you get a message when you die: "Beware, fool, the eye of the Yiga."

Comment: In addition to all that's mentioned below, they're also still vulnerable to Ancient Arrows. That said, there's several clips of people doing a short job of the entire Yiga clan, without them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I just did this part the other day, it is possible and there are 3 approaches that I found.

1. Use a really fast one handed weapon.  It is possible to stun lock them and kill them before they can whistle and summon reinforcements.  It is really hard though, and only managed to do it once.  Lightning and Ice help if you have them, but it takes a lot to do the whole hideout this way.
2. You can sneak attack them.  I had a couple of Ancient Battle Axe++ in my inventory (60 damage per hit), and if you can get up behind them (Shiekah armor helps for the stealth bonus, or sneaky food/elixers), you'll get a prompt for a sneak strike attack.  With a weapon this powerful, you can take them out in a single hit each.  Throwing the mighty bananas on the ground to lure them a certain direction (away from the others mainly) does help, although you have to be very careful on the approach.  Too much sound or being slightly to the side will cause them to see you when you get close.
3. In the second room only, you can take them all at once.  First ascend the ladder and get the pile of mighty bananas on the second floor.  Then sneak to the other ladder and climb up to the second floor catwalk, where you can access the pillar in the middle of the room with the chest on it.  If you initiate combat from up there, they will teleport up, where you can keep knocking them down to the ground floor.  Repeat until they are all dead.  This option is REALLY hard and will go through most of your weapons, shield, and probably more stamina than you have (unless you cook lots of stamina food/elixers).

Personally, I found it much easier to just sneak through the whole way, using bananas to lure the guards away from the two doors.  Kill the boss in the last room, then you can loot with no resistance on the way back out once the place is abandoned.  The drops from the guards are rarely worth the trouble you have to go through.

Comment: "With a weapon this powerful, you can take them out in a single hit each." A sneakstrike is, as far as I know, a one hit kill on anything it's possible to get them on, regardless of weapon damage. I definitely didn't have a 60 damage weapon when I did that part, but could kill them in one hit with sneakstrike. You can also get really easy sneakstrikes on those guards by distracting them with mighty bananas first.

Comment: I just did sneakstrike on everyone in the base lol. I felt like I needed to roam freely

Comment: @AnthonyGrist sneak strike most definitely does not guarantee a kill.  On stronger enemies, it does not kill them, however it will stun them long enough for you to get enough swings in to kill them.  Strong weapons against weak enemies works, but stronger ones like the Yiga guards and others take multiple hits from all but the strongest weapons.  I know this for a fact, it has happened to me many times in the game.  Maybe 60 damage weapons are excessive, I didn't experiment to find the cutoff.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Sneak strike is 10x your weapon damage. Yuga Blademasters have 600HP, so a 60 Damage Axe will 1HKO

Comment: Sneakstrikes aren't normally an instant kill but I think things might be tweaked in the hideout to encourage stealth.

Comment: What I did was sniping them with Ancient Arrows from safe spots. Except for one that I killed face to face (because I wanted the Windcleaver and didn't know it's not missable).

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, the big guys are powerful but slow, though you need to be very careful since they teleport.

They are slow enough that you can outrun them and defeat the arrow-wielding guys first without too much problem. Then you must be very careful about only challenging them one-on-one and not getting hit.

Ice arrows are indeed a great help. So are show arrow, frostblades and thunderblades.

It is very useful to note that you **can** murder one of those big guys without him calling for help, if you keep him stunned with ice and thunder, constantly until he's dead. This is fairly easy to accomplish in the first room, but in the second, accomplishing this is probably just as long and tedious as sneaking around using bananas. That's because if anybody else sees you, **they** will call for help too, even if you're good at keeping the one guy you're attacking stunned consistently.

Once the ennemies are dead the gates open up.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to do it today. In the big room with three guards I got on the second floor catwalk and made it to the corner. Behind the Triangle shaped roof. They were unable to hit me or teleport there. I picked them off one by one with bomb arrows. After about 5 kills they stopped coming and the gates opened. I hate sneaking around. Always hated the stealth genre.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be hardcoded that regardless of your equipment, buffs, and blessings, any hit from the Yiga Blademasters (the big guys) is a OHKO. If the Yiga spot you, you basically cannot be hit by the big guys at all.

One strategy that's effective but expensive is to use Ice Arrows. This will freeze the Yiga temporarily. Just keep rotating through Blademasters firing Ice Arrows one after the other.

Answer (score 1):

In the second room, I was able to defeat the whole party with the following strategy:

- Climb atop the pillar with the small surface area
- Use a frostblade to freeze enemies as they teleport in front of you
- Use a good two handed weapon to knock the frozen enemies off

The frostblade is crucial, because it's a *fast* weapon, ensuring that you can strike before the enemy does. A thunderblade probably works just as well. A frost spear might work too, but may be harder to aim. A great frostblade does *not* work; it's slow enough the enemy can get in the first strike to instantly kill you.

For added safety, your choice of two handed weapon could be a great frostblade or a great thunderblade; this ensures that the enemies are still stunned if you miss the second swing that would knock them down, and gives you an extra chance to stun a newly teleported enemy.

---

Alternating between thunder and frost blades will also let you kill a guard that has spotted you but has not yet blown his whistle; you just need to take care to ensure the guard is perpetually stunned.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible (i know this answer is late)

Here's what you need:
Blizzard Rod
Master Sword (or any other sword with 30+ damage and with good durability)

That's all. Use the blizzard rod's massive radius to freeze most of them, and pick them off one by one. You can just keep using blizzard rod to freeze them, *or* if you have the DLC, if you've beaten the master trials, Just use babarian armor and that will allow you to one-shot the yiga bow members.

Answer (score 0):

I did something weird the other day where I got caught as I was going up a ladder and then the Yiga with duplex bows spawned in, but they didn't teleport to me; they just teleported to the same spot and all of the patrolling Yiga pulled out their swords and kept swiping in the same spot. It was funny, but you might be able to use something like remote bombs at the top of the ladder to kill one close by, take the loot if there is any, and teleport out. You also might be able to use ancient arrows to kill them, but I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to take their gear, use 2 ice arrows with a good 40+ bow, combined with stasis+ if needed.  If you don't care about the gear, show them who really has the superior sheikah weapons technology by going nuclear on them by using ancient arrows for a 1 shot kill with a simple bow or a multishot bow for pure mayhem.  Or, if you can sneak up on them with a 40+ weapon for the sneakstrike you can get a 1 shot kill, but be careful not to blow your cover at that close of range or to be seen by their companions while you take them down.

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer**

Yes, it's possible to kill all the Yiga after they spot you.

**Longer Answer**

I managed to do this, although I didn't venture into the Yiga fortress until relatively late in the game.  The gear I had was:

- Upgraded 'Stasis' rune
- Savage Lynel Sword (72 damage, shortsword)
- Savage Lynel Bow (32x5 damage)
- Bomb Arrows (had 100+, but probably only used around 10)

None of those are essential, though the rune upgrade is extremely useful; especially if you don't have a massive stash of bomb arrows.

Anyhow, the basic strategy is to **keep moving and don't panic**.  The big guys with the swords will teleport around, and one hit from them and it's Game Over.  The archers are more of an annoyance, so don't worry about them initially (though feel free to take a swipe if you get a clear shot at one).

What tends to happen, as long as you keep moving, is that the sword-wielding enemies teleport to the same spot and form a big clump behind you.  If you keep a medium-range distance (just slightly beyond the blast radius of a bomb arrow) from this clump, they'll slowly plod along in your general direction instead of teleporting.  That pretty much allows you to hang back and rain bomb arrows on them with impunity.

If you don't have bomb arrows, another viable (though higher-risk) strategy is to use the obstacles around the room to peel one enemy off from the clump.  Hit him with stasis, run in for some cheap hits, and then move back out of range before he's able to get a swing of his own in.  Takes awhile, but as long as you don't allow yourself to get hit you'll eventually win.

Stasis is also useful for quickly shutting down the archers, after you've safely clumpified the swordsmen.

The ladder up to the catwalk is generally safe (although the catwalk itself is not).  A good opening move is to quickly move to the upper level and run around for a bit until all the enemies have teleported above, and then transfer back to ground level.  Makes it less likely to accidentally bump into a swordsman at the start of the fight.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily pick them off when they spot you by spamming the slomo shot with a multi shot bow using bomb arrows

Answer (score 0):

I've seen some good answers on here, so I'll help out a little bit. If you want to use the method where you use frostblades/thunderblades,(or other elemental weapons that aren't rods) here is a tip. After attacking for a little bit, (around six hits) you will no longer get the special shock/frozen effect on enemies after hitting them. You normally just wait a little bit and then use the effects again. However, you can use quick-select (with the right button on the d-pad) to go to a different weapon and then back to your elemental weapon to instantly get the shock/frozen effect back. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I saw someone do this in a video one time:

As soon as they see you get to the top of one of the pillars that are in the room. Bring the best weapons that you can since you will have to do a lot of hits to kill just one of them if you do not. Have an attack Up four buff to help you out even more. When on the top of one of the pillars, stand there until one of them teleports to you. Then freeze them with the Blizzard Rod, and one hit and they will fall down and take damage from the fall as well. At least, that's what the person in that video did.